# How to remove line numbers from code using java

Tags: java

I copied the code from somewhere to run in the eclipse but that code have line numbers.

such as,

```
 26   package java.lang;
   27   
   28   import java.util.Properties;
   29   
   30   /**
   31    * The {@code Integer} class wraps a value of the primitive type
   32    * {@code int} in an object. An object of type {@code Integer}
   33    * contains a single field whose type is {@code int}.
   34    *
   35    * <p>In addition, this class provides several methods for converting
   36    * an {@code int} to a {@code String} and a {@code String} to an
   37    * {@code int}, as well as other constants and methods useful when
   38    * dealing with an {@code int}.
   39    *
   40    * <p>Implementation note: The implementations of the "bit twiddling"
   41    * methods (such as {@link #highestOneBit(int) highestOneBit} and
   42    * {@link #numberOfTrailingZeros(int) numberOfTrailingZeros}) are
   43    * based on material from Henry S. Warren, Jr.'s <i>Hacker's
   44    * Delight</i>, (Addison Wesley, 2002).
   45    *
   46    * @author  Lee Boynton
   47    * @author  Arthur van Hoff
   48    * @author  Josh Bloch
   49    * @author  Joseph D. Darcy
   50    * @since JDK1.0
   51    */
   52   public final class Integer extends Number implements Comparable<Integer> {
   53       /**
   54        * A constant holding the minimum value an {@code int} can
   55        * have, -2<sup>31</sup>.
   56        */
   57       public static final int   MIN_VALUE = 0x80000000;
   58   
   59       /**
   60        * A constant holding the maximum value an {@code int} can
   61        * have, 2<sup>31</sup>-1.
   62        */
   63       public static final int   MAX_VALUE = 0x7fffffff;
   64   
   65       /**
   66        * The {@code Class} instance representing the primitive type
   67        * {@code int}.
   68        *
   69        * @since   JDK1.1
   70        */
   71       public static final Class<Integer>  TYPE = (Class<Integer>) Class.getPrimitiveClass("int");
   72   
   73       /**
   74        * All possible chars for representing a number as a String
   75        */
   76       final static char[] digits = {
   77           '0' , '1' , '2' , '3' , '4' , '5' ,
   78           '6' , '7' , '8' , '9' , 'a' , 'b' ,
   79           'c' , 'd' , 'e' , 'f' , 'g' , 'h' ,
   80           'i' , 'j' , 'k' , 'l' , 'm' , 'n' ,
   81           'o' , 'p' , 'q' , 'r' , 's' , 't' ,
   82           'u' , 'v' , 'w' , 'x' , 'y' , 'z'
   83       };
   84        }
```

It is impossible to delete numbers line by line, if file contains thousands of line. I am trying to write the algorithm to remove the line numbers from each line, but not succeeded. I want this -

```
      package java.lang;

   import java.util.Properties;

   /**
    * The {@code Integer} class wraps a value of the primitive type
    * {@code int} in an object. An object of type {@code Integer}
    * contains a single field whose type is {@code int}.
    *
    * <p>In addition, this class provides several methods for converting
    * an {@code int} to a {@code String} and a {@code String} to an
    * {@code int}, as well as other constants and methods useful when
    * dealing with an {@code int}.
    *
    * <p>Implementation note: The implementations of the "bit twiddling"
    * methods (such as {@link #highestOneBit(int) highestOneBit} and
    * {@link #numberOfTrailingZeros(int) numberOfTrailingZeros}) are
    * based on material from Henry S. Warren, Jr.'s <i>Hacker's
    * Delight</i>, (Addison Wesley, 2002).
    *
    * @author  Lee Boynton
    * @author  Arthur van Hoff
    * @author  Josh Bloch
    * @author  Joseph D. Darcy
    * @since JDK1.0
    */
   public final class Integer extends Number implements Comparable<Integer> {
       /**
        * A constant holding the minimum value an {@code int} can
        * have, -2<sup>31</sup>.
        */
       public static final int   MIN_VALUE = 0x80000000;

       /**
        * A constant holding the maximum value an {@code int} can
        * have, 2<sup>31</sup>-1.
        */
       public static final int   MAX_VALUE = 0x7fffffff;

       /**
        * The {@code Class} instance representing the primitive type
        * {@code int}.
        *
        * @since   JDK1.1
        */
       public static final Class<Integer>  TYPE = (Class<Integer>) Class.getPrimitiveClass("int");

       /**
        * All possible chars for representing a number as a String
        */
       final static char[] digits = {
           '0' , '1' , '2' , '3' , '4' , '5' ,
           '6' , '7' , '8' , '9' , 'a' , 'b' ,
           'c' , 'd' , 'e' , 'f' , 'g' , 'h' ,
           'i' , 'j' , 'k' , 'l' , 'm' , 'n' ,
           'o' , 'p' , 'q' , 'r' , 's' , 't' ,
           'u' , 'v' , 'w' , 'x' , 'y' , 'z'
       };
```

I will appreciate for your suggestions & answers.

Comment: I suspect you'd find it easier to get hold of the source in a form that doesn't have line numbers to start with. Where did you get the file? Do they really not have an export feature?

Comment: Why java?  There are many tools that can do this already, why create another?  sed, awk, perl..

Comment: Use a text editor that can replace with regular expression like notepad++ and replace `^(\s+)?\d+` with nothing.

Comment: You could also do this by pasting the text in an editor that supports column-selection (like Eclipse, Notepad++, VIM, ...) and use it to delete all line-numbers at once.

Comment: @user432 Maybe just post that comment as an answer, so we can bring this off the unanswered feed.

Comment: If you are on Linux, `cat file.java | cut -f2 -d ' ' > file.java` will do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a text editor that supports regular expressions for replacing(e.g. notepad++) and replace `^(\s+)?\d+` with nothing.

Explanation:

`^` start of line

`(\s+)?` whitespace or nothing

`\d+` numbers

As pointed out in the comments you can just use eclipse since it supports regex-based replacing.

How-to for notepad++:

Open your file, then open replace dialog with shortcut CTRL+H, then put `^(\s+)?\d+` in "Find What:" and make sure "Replace With:" is empty. Set the chexkbox for "Regular Expression" in the bottom left corner. Finally click "Replace All".

Comment: The editor in Eclipse supports regex-based search and replace.

Comment: Kindly tell me the steps, How to do this in eclipse ?

Comment: @GopalSingh added it to the answer. Hope it is correct since I don't use eclipse anymore.

Comment: Then plz tell me steps, how to do this in noteped++.

Comment: @GopalSingh open your file, then open replace dialog with shortcut CTRL+H, then put `^(\s+)?\d+` in "Find What:" and make sure "Replace With:" is empty. Set the chexkbox for "Regular Expression" in the bottom left corner. Finally click "Replace All".

Comment: vote up requires minimum 15 reputation. I don't have.

Comment: @GopalSingh Accepting and votes are two different things. You opened the question and can therefore accept one of the answers. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235) for how to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

i have also 2 solutions to your problem. there are a little bit different. if you do that a lot of times, i suggest you write an algorithm. But if you use it for once you can use my methods.

i use office programs to do this kind of things.

you can use excel to do that.
1- Copy all the lines to excel rows.
2- Use excel functions to cut the first 3 or 4 digits.(you can use MID function: (=MID(the cell that includes program; start character number ; how many character that you want )))
(4 or 5 works as a start character if there is a line number like 1200)
(1000 works as a character that you want)
=MID(A1;5;1000)

if all the spaces equal between line number and code. you can also use word to do that.
1- Copy Paste all the program lines
2- Convert it to the tables. Use the spaces between line number and code line as a column separator. (in the section "Separate text at", you should type space five or Six times depends on your program)
3- Delete first column which includes all the line numbers.
4- Convert it to text.